Was the historical Hur’q presence on Qo’nos reached through the Bajoran Wormhole or other Faster than Warp means?
In Star Trek, the Klingon historical object, the sword of Kahless was stolen by an alien race, the Hur’q around 1000 AD. In Deep Space Nine, the Location of the sword is eventually found, on what was supposed a Hur’q dominated (at one point) planet in the Gamma Quadrant. It is never explicitly made clear if this was the Hur’q homeworld or not. It was also, to my surprise never stated in the episode the inference that the Hur’q originally took the Sword and raided Qo’nos after reaching the locality of Qo’nos through the wormhole. It has been noted in Deep Space Nine episodes that the wormhole had existed and been open prior to the start of deep space Nine, as there are incidences of historical historians in advertently discovering the wormhole/temple. It would be incredibly coincidental to me, if the Hur’q had just happened to use some other faster than warp travel to reach an area that was so close to the other end of a wormhole that was close to one of their planets, but it also surprises me that it is never explicitly stated what would be a notable historical fact once the discovery of the sword was made.
Is it ever made explicitly true the Hur’q reached Qo’nos through the wormhole? Wouldn’t this Pre-Emissary interaction be of note to Historians?

In canon, we don't know. In the video games, they used tame wormhole tech to move around the galaxy at rapid speeds; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hur%27q

@Valorum And in the video games, it’s just coincidence that where the final resting place of the sword was just happened to be at the other end of a stable wormhole near the place they stole it from? I’ve never really played many Star Trek video games so I’m just asking

I can't remember if it's ever established. Certainly they have the ability to make their own stable wormholes, so they might have gained that from the study of natural wormholes? Dunno.

Within the main canon, they exist solely in a few scraps of dialogue and nothing is ever established about them except that the Klingons's 'first contact' was with them, they hung around for a bit and then left.

@Valorum I know, I would just think that historical usage of the wormhole before the official “discovery” would be a big deal, I know they mention a couple of Bajorans who discovered it And there was one guy who was stuck in there. It does surprise me to know that outside of Canon they supposedly had their own artificial wormhole technology, because the discovery of the sword that they stole was centered around far away travel that could be used through a real wormhole. it seems like a big coincidence yet they never explicitly state It was through the Bajoran wormhole in the episode

I think the implication being that when the Klingons became a galactic empire they surely would have a grudge against the Hur’q. And since the sword's location was still a mystery the discovery that they were from the Gamma quadrant explains why the Klingons never retaliated.  At that point it seems analogous to a one off raid by Vikings on North America so of course one would assume the Hur’q used the wormhole.
